# Using lsmeans compare results to add significance bars and stars to ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have kind of asked this before but still haven't gotten anywhere.

I have a barplot that is pretty complicated. I had to take the original dataframe results and re-arrange them so I could plot it correctly. I am super happy with the plot itself.

I am trying to add asterisks to the plot calculated with `lsmeans`, as that uses my model.

I would like to get my `lsmeans` data into the right format so `stat_pvalue_manual` can read it in my ggplot.

Here we go:

1. Run `lsmeans`

`lsmeanstest <- lsmeans(d.lme, pairwise~Group*Sex*CS.NCS, adjust="tukey")`

2. Turn `lsmeans` results into a dataframe

`posthoc <- data.frame(lsmeanstest$contrasts)`

Result:

```
posthoc
                          contrast   estimate       SE df    t.ratio      p.value
1    Con Female CS - PNS Female CS  211.72049 71.46912 18  2.9624049 1.169197e-01
2      Con Female CS - Con Male CS  358.23947 69.65949 49  5.1427234 1.216136e-04
3      Con Female CS - PNS Male CS  307.46996 69.65949 18  4.4138993 6.449545e-03
4   Con Female CS - Con Female NCS   35.68161 71.46912 49  0.4992590 9.996151e-01
5   Con Female CS - PNS Female NCS  337.15551 71.46912 18  4.7174987 3.422337e-03
6     Con Female CS - Con Male NCS  413.57023 69.65949 49  5.9370267 7.786261e-06
7     Con Female CS - PNS Male NCS  491.51236 71.46912 18  6.8772685 4.453535e-05
8      PNS Female CS - Con Male CS  146.51898 69.65949 18  2.1033601 4.484333e-01
9      PNS Female CS - PNS Male CS   95.74947 69.65949 49  1.3745360 8.642252e-01
10  PNS Female CS - Con Female NCS -176.03888 71.46912 18 -2.4631459 2.709620e-01
11  PNS Female CS - PNS Female NCS  125.43502 71.46912 49  1.7550938 6.521321e-01
12    PNS Female CS - Con Male NCS  201.84974 69.65949 18  2.8976633 1.313370e-01
13    PNS Female CS - PNS Male NCS  279.79187 71.46912 49  3.9148636 6.305701e-03
14       Con Male CS - PNS Male CS  -50.76951 67.80156 18 -0.7487956 9.938626e-01
15    Con Male CS - Con Female NCS -322.55786 69.65949 49 -4.6304945 6.704281e-04
16    Con Male CS - PNS Female NCS  -21.08397 69.65949 18 -0.3026719 9.999830e-01
17      Con Male CS - Con Male NCS   55.33076 67.80156 49  0.8160690 9.913801e-01
18      Con Male CS - PNS Male NCS  133.27289 69.65949 18  1.9132052 5.595949e-01
19    PNS Male CS - Con Female NCS -271.78835 69.65949 18 -3.9016704 1.864489e-02
20    PNS Male CS - PNS Female NCS   29.68555 69.65949 49  0.4261522 9.998657e-01
21      PNS Male CS - Con Male NCS  106.10027 67.80156 18  1.5648646 7.638912e-01
22      PNS Male CS - PNS Male NCS  184.04240 69.65949 49  2.6420293 1.659374e-01
23 Con Female NCS - PNS Female NCS  301.47390 71.46912 18  4.2182397 9.693650e-03
24   Con Female NCS - Con Male NCS  377.88862 69.65949 49  5.4247977 4.633011e-05
25   Con Female NCS - PNS Male NCS  455.83075 71.46912 18  6.3780095 1.166243e-04
26   PNS Female NCS - Con Male NCS   76.41472 69.65949 18  1.0969751 9.493203e-01
27   PNS Female NCS - PNS Male NCS  154.35685 71.46912 49  2.1597698 3.931364e-01
28     Con Male NCS - PNS Male NCS   77.94213 69.65949 18  1.1189019 9.440858e-01
```

3. Re-arrange dataframe into group1, group2, and p-value so `stat_pvalue_manual` is happy.

```
posthocsep <- separate(
              posthoc,
              contrast,
              c("group1", "group2"),
              sep = "-")
```

4. Get rid of extra stuff I don't need for plotting significance

```
posthocsepkeep <- posthocsep[keeps]
```

5. Add asterisks

```
posthocsepkeep$asterisk<-ifelse(posthocsepkeep$p.value<0.10 & posthocsepkeep$p.value>0.05, paste("~"),
                         ifelse(posthocsepkeep$p.value<0.05 & posthocsepkeep$p.value>0.001, paste("*"),     
                         ifelse(posthocsepkeep$p.value<0.001 & posthocsepkeep$p.value>0.0001, paste("**"),
                         ifelse(posthocsepkeep$p.value<0.0001, paste("***"), paste("NS")))))
```

I get this:

```
> posthocsepkeep
            group1          group2      p.value asterisk
1   Con Female CS    PNS Female CS 1.169197e-01       NS
2   Con Female CS      Con Male CS 1.216136e-04       **
3   Con Female CS      PNS Male CS 6.449545e-03        *
4   Con Female CS   Con Female NCS 9.996151e-01       NS
5   Con Female CS   PNS Female NCS 3.422337e-03        *
6   Con Female CS     Con Male NCS 7.786261e-06      ***
7   Con Female CS     PNS Male NCS 4.453535e-05      ***
8   PNS Female CS      Con Male CS 4.484333e-01       NS
9   PNS Female CS      PNS Male CS 8.642252e-01       NS
10  PNS Female CS   Con Female NCS 2.709620e-01       NS
11  PNS Female CS   PNS Female NCS 6.521321e-01       NS
12  PNS Female CS     Con Male NCS 1.313370e-01       NS
13  PNS Female CS     PNS Male NCS 6.305701e-03        *
14    Con Male CS      PNS Male CS 9.938626e-01       NS
15    Con Male CS   Con Female NCS 6.704281e-04       **
16    Con Male CS   PNS Female NCS 9.999830e-01       NS
17    Con Male CS     Con Male NCS 9.913801e-01       NS
18    Con Male CS     PNS Male NCS 5.595949e-01       NS
19    PNS Male CS   Con Female NCS 1.864489e-02        *
20    PNS Male CS   PNS Female NCS 9.998657e-01       NS
21    PNS Male CS     Con Male NCS 7.638912e-01       NS
22    PNS Male CS     PNS Male NCS 1.659374e-01       NS
23 Con Female NCS   PNS Female NCS 9.693650e-03        *
24 Con Female NCS     Con Male NCS 4.633011e-05      ***
25 Con Female NCS     PNS Male NCS 1.166243e-04       **
26 PNS Female NCS     Con Male NCS 9.493203e-01       NS
27 PNS Female NCS     PNS Male NCS 3.931364e-01       NS
28   Con Male NCS     PNS Male NCS 9.440858e-01       NS
```

Sweet.

But now I'm stuck.

How do I get these results into the `stat_pvalue_manual` format: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_pvalue_manual.html

This is how I plot the actual data - like I said I have had to rearrange it to accommodate my three factors:

```
corttestplotsummary <- ddply(d, c("CS.NCS", "Sex", "Group"), summarize,
                             N    = sum(!is.na(Corticosterone)),
                             mean = mean(Corticosterone, na.rm = TRUE),
                             sd   = sd(Corticosterone, na.rm = TRUE),
                             se   = sd / sqrt(N))

corttestplotsummaryomit <- na.omit(corttestplotsummary)

corttestunitedcol <- unite(corttestplotsummaryomit, Treatment_Status, c(CS.NCS, Group), remove=TRUE)

x <- c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS")

corttestunitedcol %>%
  mutate(Treatment_Status =  factor(Treatment_Status, levels = x)) %>%
  arrange(Treatment_Status)  


p<- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(~Sex, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                      panel.border = element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major.x=element_blank() ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  labs(title="Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =c("#f77f00","#d62828", "#EAE2B7","#fcbf49"),
                    name="Status\nTreatment",
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress"))
```

Comment: Can you please `dput` the dataset corttestunitedcol and posthocsepkeep so I can try it with the data. Just thinking about solutions won't work. (dput means write dput(corttestunitedcol) and dput(posthocsepkeep) in your R and copy the results (strucutre(list.....)) )